# Hole in the middle of coord_polar not showing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have a "hole" in the middle of the coord, but its not showing. Tried changing the x-variable. Any ideas?

```
structure(list(name = c("g__Bradyrhizobium", "g__Bradyrhizobium", 
"g__Cutibacterium", "g__Cutibacterium"), primaryTumorLocation = c("Small intestine", 
"Urothelial tract", "Small intestine", "Urothelial tract"), absolute = c(2L, 
10L, 9L, 25L), Freq = c(0.032258064516129, 0.072992700729927, 
0.145161290322581, 0.182481751824818), percent = c(7.5, 16.9, 
33.5, 42.2)), row.names = c(1390L, 1397L, 2470L, 2477L), class = "data.frame")


ggplot(df) +
geom_col(aes(x=4,y=Freq)) + 
  coord_polar("y",start = 0,direction = 1) + 
  facet_grid(name~primaryTumorLocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does manually setting the limits of the x position not help? Below, `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3, NA))` sets the lower limit to 3. You can choose a smaller limit if you want a bigger hole.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.1

df <- structure(
  list(
    name = c("g__Bradyrhizobium", "g__Bradyrhizobium", 
             "g__Cutibacterium", "g__Cutibacterium"), 
    primaryTumorLocation = c("Small intestine", "Urothelial tract", 
                             "Small intestine", "Urothelial tract"), 
    absolute = c(2L, 10L, 9L, 25L), 
    Freq = c(0.032258064516129, 0.072992700729927, 0.145161290322581, 
             0.182481751824818), 
    percent = c(7.5, 16.9, 33.5, 42.2)
  ), 
  row.names = c(1390L, 1397L, 2470L, 2477L), 
  class = "data.frame"
)


ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x=4,y=Freq)) + 
  coord_polar("y",start = 0,direction = 1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3, NA)) +
  facet_grid(name~primaryTumorLocation)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: is it also possible to add the "absolute" value in the middle of the hole. Maybe as a geom_text?